# How to know in trace() exit handler if exception was raised by the function

Tags: r

Is there a way to know in the `trace()` `exit` handler if the function raised an unhandled exception? Currently I use `geterrmessage()`, but it catches handled exceptions in other libraries internals, which is not what I need.

```r
other_silent <- function() try(stop("irrelevant", call. = FALSE), silent = TRUE)
other_error <- function() stop("relevant", call. = FALSE)

my_silent <- function() other_silent()
my_error <- function() other_error()

trace(c("my_silent", "my_error"), print = FALSE,
      tracer = quote({.Internal(seterrmessage(""))}), 
      exit = quote({print(geterrmessage())}))

my_silent()
my_error()
```

The call to `my_silent()` produces output:

```
[1] "Error : irrelevant\n"
```

While I need it to remain silent, because the function itself finished successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own version of trace using code from `methods` as basis.

```r
mytrace <- function(what) {
  where <- environment(sys.function())
  def <- getFunction(what, where = where)
  body(def, envir = environment(def)) <- rlang::expr({
    exception <- NA
    tryCatch(!!body(def), error = function(e) {
      exception <<- e
      stop(e)
    }, finally = {<log method with or without exception>})
  })
  assign(what, def, where)
}
```